# criteo tags on ajax site

Tags: javascript, turbolinks, criteo

I have an issue with integrating criteo tags into my ajax website.
Everything works perfectly when I send my first event.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//static.criteo.net/js/ld/ld.js" async="true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.criteo_q = window.criteo_q || [];
window.criteo_q.push(event_data);
</script>
```

But when I try to send another event into criteo without page reload it does not work. Event does not appear in criteo.

```
<script>
window.criteo_q.push(event_data);
</script>
```

Any ideas what is wrong?

Demo example: of https://jsfiddle.net/36jq9dLu/156/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should programmatically reimport the loader every time you want to fire a new event. This won't cause any latency as the loader is cached by the browser, but is necessary as it contains some code useful to reinitialize the `criteo_q` object. You can add the following lines before every event fire:

```
window.criteo_q = undefined;
script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = '//static.criteo.net/js/ld/ld.js';
script.async = 'true'
document.head.appendChild(script);
window.criteo_q = window.criteo_q || [];
```

https://jsfiddle.net/36jq9dLu/199/

Comment: Thank you. 
But it must be `window.criteo_q = [];` or `window.criteo_q = undefined;` instead of `window.criteo_q = window.criteo_q || [];`
because of the first line in `//static.criteo.net/js/ld/ld.js` criteo object wont be reinitialized `if (!window.criteo_q || window.criteo_q instanceof Array) {`

Comment: Also I did some debugging and found a better solution. Criteo sends its events by adding `iframe` and `script` tags into `div id="criteo-tags-div"`. Criteo script caches this div into a variable and does not reset this variable when page is changed (in my case the whole document.body is replaced when page is changed). So before page change I detach `#criteo-tags-div` and append it into document.body after page is changed.

Comment: I'm not sure about your solution because part of the events are also sent as query parameters in the call, so I would always set `window.criteo_q = undefined;`to ensure all previous data is erased. `window.criteo_q = window.criteo_q || [];` is useful to ensure that the browser finds a valid `criteo_q` object since the loader injection is asyncrounous.

Answer (score 0):

In order for Criteo OneTag to properly evaluate events after DOM-change you should set widget to non-blocking mode by using **requiresDOM** parameter.

```
...
  events = [
  { event: 'setAccount', account: 123456 },
  { event: 'setHashedEmail', email: '1234567890asdf' },
  { event: 'setSiteType', type: 'd' },
  { event: 'viewHome' },
  { requiresDOM: "non-blocking", cb:
    $(document.body).on("page:changed", function() {
       product_event =
[
        { event: 'setAccount', account: 123456 },
        { event: 'setHashedEmail', email: '1234567890asdf' },
        { event: 'setSiteType', type: 'd' },       
        { event: "viewItem", product: 123 }    

]
        criteo_q.push(product_event)    
    })    
  }

]

window.criteo_q.push(events);
...
```

Following snippet demonstrates this:

https://jsfiddle.net/yuxqrfev/5/